# Re-Initialize Firebase default app Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to change my default Firebase app. When I try to re-initialize the new app, it says throws an error that a default app already exists. I can't delete the default app either.

How can I delete the instance of that default Firebase app for me to initialize a new one or be able to switch which one the default is?

Currently I am using the Firebase options to initialize the app:

```
FirebaseOptions envOptions =
     FirebaseOptions(
             apiKey: apiKey['name'],
             appId: appId['name'],
             messagingSenderId: msgSendr['name'],
                projectId: projId['name'],
             databaseURL: dbUrl['name'],
             authDomain: auth['name']);
         //Initialize app with those details
try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: envOptions);
} catch (e) {}
```

I want to be able to pass a new app's credentials and initialize that. How can I do that?

Comment: You can’t do that. You can initialize a named Firebase app and use it instead of the default one.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks. The default has to stay then.